# Express $y = 2 \sin 2(x + \frac{\pi}{4}) - \cos2(x + \frac{\pi}{4})$ in the form $ y = A \sin k x + B \cos k x$

Tags: trigonometry

Express $y = 2 \sin 2(x + \frac{\pi}{4}) - \cos2(x + \frac{\pi}{4})$ in the form $ y = A \sin k x + B \cos k x$

I don't know what to do about the '2' after the sine and cosine. (We have been using the form $y = a \sin k (x -\beta)$, so I am referring to the value 'k' or the frequency).

We have been shown how to work examples without a value for 'k' present, using the addition formulas.

So $y = 2 \sin (x + \frac{\pi}{4}) - \cos(x + \frac{\pi}{4})$ would start to be solved as follows:
$$y = 2 \sin (x + \frac{\pi}{4}) - \cos(x + \frac{\pi}{4})$$ 
$$ = 2(\sin x \cos \frac{\pi}{4} + \cos x \sin\frac{\pi}{4}) - (\cos x \cos\frac{\pi}{4}  - \sin x \sin \frac{\pi}{4} ) $$  and so on...

However, if I attempt $y = 2 \sin 2(x + \frac{\pi}{4}) - \cos2(x + \frac{\pi}{4})$ like this I get $y = 2 \sin(2x + \frac{\pi}{2}) - \cos (2x + \frac{\pi}{2}) $ and then it looks like I am going to need one of the double angle formulae to deal with $\sin 2x$ and $\cos 2x$

Some help getting started with the method we are required to use would really be appreciated.

Comment: Double angle formulas aren't necessary here because they want trig functions of the form $\sin(kx)$ and $\cos(kx)$ in your solution where, in this case, $k=2$.

Comment: Thank you, that gave me the confidence to continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Christopher Toni, Adi Dani and  Sami Ben Romdhane, they solved or helped solve this for me. I want to put this as an answer because it uses the method required in the OP, not because I am trying to claim credit for the answer.
$$y=2\sin2(x+\frac{\pi}{4})-\cos2(x+\frac{\pi}{4})$$
$$=2\sin (2x+\frac{\pi}{2})-\cos(2x+\frac{\pi}{2})$$
Using $\sin \frac{\pi}{2} = 1$ and $\cos \frac{\pi}{2} = 0$ and the method required in the OP:

$$= 2(\sin2x\cos \frac{\pi}{2} + \cos2x\sin \frac{\pi}{2}) - (\cos2x \cos \frac{\pi}{2} - \sin 2x \sin \frac{\pi}{2})$$
$$= (2\cos2x . 1) -( - \sin 2x .1)$$
$$ = 2\cos 2x - (- \sin 2x)$$
$$ =\sin 2x + 2\cos2x$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Use these equalities
$$\sin\left(y+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\cos y$$
and
$$\cos\left(y+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=-\sin y$$

Comment: Good time Sami :)

Answer (score 1):

$$y=2\sin2(x+\frac{\pi}{4})-\cos2(x+\frac{\pi}{4})=$$
$$=2\sin (2x+\frac{\pi}{2})-\cos(2x+\frac{\pi}{2})$$
$$=2\cos2x-(-\sin2x)=$$
$$=\sin2x+2\cos2x$$
$$A=1,B=2,k=2$$